# Testing for IE with PHP

Tags: php, css, cross-browser, browser-detection

I am developing a web page that will be used in several different contexts, and while I normally avoid browser sniffing and conditional statements at all costs, there is just no way around it this time.

I'm trying a simple method, and I was hoping I could get some feedback on whether this is a good idea or not.

I am testing for the user agent and then echoing a class on the element in the html (in my case, a div) if the user agent is IE.

```
<?php echo (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), 'msie') !== FALSE) ? ('classforie') : (''); ?>
```

Then in my css, I am doing something along the lines of this;

```
.classone { display: inline-block; }
.classone.classforie { zoom: 1; display: inline; }
```

Note, the CSS isn't the important part, I just made that up for the sake of example. I'm just wondering if doing things this way is a good practice or not?

Comment: Can you say why it is you think there's no way around it this time? :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html). User agent sniffing is unreliable.

Comment: I thought conditional comments were bad, but now that I did a second look on Google, I can't find much about that. Are there any downsides to using conditional comments (other than the obvious maintainability concerns)?

Comment: They are the standard approach for solving this type of problem, and less problematic then any of the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

```
.classone.classforie { zoom: 1; display: inline; }
```

Definitely does not work in IE6.

The way I've usually seen it done is to output the class on the BODY tag.  I think there might be some issues with IE6 and classes on the HTML tag.

Then you will have something like this:

```
.msie .classone { zoom: 1; display: inline; }
```

Comment: I'd also like to add that you can just use a conditional css include in your html and add all your MSIE class declarations in it.  <!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->

Comment: Sorry, I should have been a little clearer, the class is going on a <div> in my html, not on the html element itself.

Comment: Also, in this case, I actually don't have access to the <head> of the document. So that's another reason to add to my list for not using a <link> or conditional statements.

Comment: Then I would still place the class on the parent element of the element you're trying to target.  Nesting classes isn't supported by IE6.